# Swift iOS -UrlSession moving very slow. Is there a way to do multiple tasks at once?

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement, grand-central-dispatch, nsurlsession

I have array of urls, there can be anywhere from 1 to 6 images inside the array, never more then that.

The curent loop I'm using now works but the UrlSession moves ridiculously slow. It takes almost 1-2 minutes to upload 6 images to Firebase. I've tried it with while running Xcode and while not running Xcode and no matter what it moves really slow. My network is fast so it's not that.

I've read multiple SO posts that says the key is to put the completionHandler on the main queue which is what I've tried to no avail.

Is there a way I can execute multiple UrlSessions all at once instead of looping through them?

This works but moves slowwwww:

```
var urls = [URL]()
picUUID = UUID().uuidString
dict = [String:Any]()

let myGroup = DispatchGroup()
var count = 0

for url in urls{

    myGroup.enter() // enter group here
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data, let _ = error else { return }

            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                self.firstLoopUrlsToSendDataToStorage("\(self.picUUID)_\(self.count).jpg", picData: data)
                self.count += 1
            }
     }).resume()

    // send dictionary data to firebase when loop is done
    myGroup.notify(queue: .global(qos: .background)) {
        self.secondWhenLoopIsFinishedSendDictToFirebaseDatabase()
        self.count = 0
    }
}

func firstLoopUrlsToSendDataToStorage(_ picId: String, picData: Data?){

    dict.updateValue(picId, forKey:"picId_\(count)")

    let picRef = storageRoot.child("pics")
    picRef.putData(picData!, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in

        if let picUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString{

             self.dict.updateValue(picUrl, forKey:"picUrl_\(count)")
             self.myGroup.leave() // leave group here
        }else{
             self.myGroup.leave() // leave group if picUrl is nil
        }
    }
}

func secondWhenLoopIsFinishedSendDictToFirebaseDatabase(){

    let ref = dbRoot.child("myRef")
    ref.updateChildValues(dict, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in

         DispatchQueue.main.async{
               self.displaySuccessAlert()
         }
    }
}
```

I looked at this [guy's Medium post](https://medium.com/@sdrzn/handling-multiple-urlsession-tasks-efficiently-91c0957a7d77) ands thinking of combining it with a switch statement since there can only be 1-6 urls but I can't figure out a way to know when all of them are finished so that I can run my `secondWhenLoopIsFinishedSendDictToFirebaseDatabase()` function

```
fileprivate func multipleUsrlTaskSessionsAtOnce(){

        switch userComplaintImageUrls.count {
        case 0:
            let urlZero = userComplaintImageUrls[0]
            TaskManager.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                // how to know when all of them are completed?
            }
            break
        case 1:
            let urlOne = userComplaintImageUrls[1]
            TaskManager.shared.dataTask(with: urlOne ) { (data, response, error) in
                // how to know when all of them are completed?
            }
            break
        case 2:
            let urlTwo = userComplaintImageUrls[2]
            TaskManager.shared.dataTask(with: urlTwo) { (data, response, error) in
                // how to know when all of them are completed?
            }
            break
        case 3:
            let urlThree = userComplaintImageUrls[3]
            TaskManager.shared.dataTask(with: urlThree) { (data, response, error) in
                // how to know when all of them are completed?
            }
            break
        case 4:
            let urlFour = userComplaintImageUrls[4]
            TaskManager.shared.dataTask(with: urlFour) { (data, response, error) in
                // how to know when all of them are completed?
            }
            break
        case 0:
            let urlFive = userComplaintImageUrls[5]
            TaskManager.shared.dataTask(with: urlFive) { (data, response, error) in
                // how to know when all of them are completed?
            }
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

TaskManager Class:

```
class TaskManager {
    static let shared = TaskManager()

    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

    typealias completionHandler = (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void

    var tasks = [URL: [completionHandler]]()

    func dataTask(with url: URL, completion: @escaping completionHandler) {
        if tasks.keys.contains(url) {
            tasks[url]?.append(completion)
        } else {
            tasks[url] = [completion]
            let _ = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    print("Finished network task")

                    guard let completionHandlers = self?.tasks[url] else { return }
                    for handler in completionHandlers {

                        print("Executing completion block")

                        handler(data, response, error)
                    }
                }
            }).resume()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way I can execute multiple UrlSessions all at once instead of looping through them?

Just the opposite. For optimal speed, you want *one* URLSession that *you* configure and store (i.e. *not* the shared session), that is used for all your different tasks. The session will be able to schedule these and reduce your latency.